# Google Cloud Endpoints: serve XML

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Quick and easy question: is there a way to make Google Endpoints to serve XML file? I'm using the "Java way".

I tried issuing

```
curl -H "Accept: application/xml" http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/baclavgae/v1/categories
```

but it keeps serving me JSON.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Endpoints only supports JSON as the wire format, at the moment.

Comment: Is there any future plan for supporting XML? I guess it would be fairly simple to implement: the marshalling/unmarshalling is already there.

Comment: There's no announced plans to support anything other than JSON.